# Dapper.FluentMap bug for nullable decimal

Tags: c#, dapper, dapper-fluentmap

I was looking to find a simple way to map a class property to a table column and I found Dapper fluent map which I thought was going to be a great alternative to the considerable boilerplate code that one would need to write simply to map a property to a column. But it does not seem to work.

```
FluentMapper.Initialize(c =>
{
    c.AddMap(new MarginSummaryMap());
});

[Serializable]
[Table("PbCash")]
public class MarginSummary : Entity
{
    public long RunId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? BusinessDate { get; set; }
    [Write(false)]
    public DateTime ProcessDate { get; set; }
    public string Broker { get; set; }
    public string BrokerAccountId { get; set; }
    public string Account { get; set; }
    public string Folio { get; set; }
    public decimal? ActualExcessOrDeficit { get; set; }
    [Write(false)]
    public decimal? ProjectedExcessOrDeficit { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}

public class MarginSummaryMap : EntityMap<MarginSummary>
{
    public MarginSummaryMap()
    {
        Map(c => c.ActualExcessOrDeficit).ToColumn("ExcessOrDeficit");
    }
}
```

Then when I am trying to save data I get an exception that the column `ActualExcessOrDeficit` does not exist in the table. Well it does not and the mapping is supposed to convert to the actual column `ExcessOrDeficit`.

Looks like this is a bug in `Dapper.FluentMap` since the problem goes way if I change type from `decimal?` to `decimal`.

Did anyone have this working - I would love to know how to fix this.

Comment: It is a previously reported issue in FluentMap https://github.com/henkmollema/Dapper-FluentMap/issues/70

Comment: It seems that the problem occurs with any Nullable property

Comment: @Anand what query are you trying to execute. Do you have an example? And which versions of Dapper and Dapper.FluentMap are you using.

Comment: @HenkMollema I am using 1.50.5 QueryEntityAsync